# What does it mean to *accelerate* the convergence of an iterative method?

Tags: soft-question, numerical-methods, definition

First time reader of some numerical analysis papers, and I haven't come across a straight forward definition of *acceleration of convergence*. I'm guessing it means to improve convergence by a certain standard of magnitude. But what is the criteria for improvement that qualifies as *acceleration*; is there a formal definition?

Comment: To increase the number of correct digits returned at each step? Say, some method doubles the number of correct digits at each step, after acceleration it could triple the number - though this is not formal or general

Comment: Travel close to the speed of light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1~}^\infty$ be as sequence, such that 
$$x_n \rightarrow \alpha, \quad n \rightarrow \infty, \quad n \in \mathbb{N},$$
and let $\{\tilde{x}_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence obtained from $\{x_n\}_{n=1~}^\infty$. We say, that $\{\tilde{x}_n\}$ converges faster than $\{ x_n\}$ to $\alpha$ provided $$ \frac{\tilde{x}_n- \alpha}{x_n - \alpha} \rightarrow 0, \quad n \rightarrow \infty, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

These [notes](https://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/234107/Spring2013/ho/WCFiles/Aitken_Delta_square-process.pdf) are not a bad place to start reading about the acceleration of sequences.